How to output `\N` in MySQL 5.7 when redirecting from a SQL script?
I have the following example.sql file:
SELECT '\N', '\\N', SUBSTRING('\\N', 1, 2), SUBSTRING('\\N', 2, 2), CONCAT('\\', 'N');

Executing it with mysql <example.sql or cat example.sql | mysql outputs:
N   \N  SUBSTRING('\\N', 1, 2)  SUBSTRING('\\N', 2, 2)  CONCAT('\\', 'N')
N   \\N \\N N   \\N

Creating example-2.sql:
source example.sql

And mysql <example-2.sql has the same output.
But executing via source in the mysql shell outputs:
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| N | \N | SUBSTRING('\\N', 1, 2) | SUBSTRING('\\N', 2, 2) | CONCAT('\\', 'N') |
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| N | \N | \N                     | N                      | \N                |
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+

Using mysql -e "SELECT '\\N', '\\\\N', SUBSTRING('\\\\N', 1, 2), SUBSTRING('\\\\N', 2, 2), CONCAT('\\\\', 'N');" has the same output.
The salient difference in output is the \N vs the \\N. Is there a way to get these to be consistent (preferably having \\N output \N) or at least get the first one to output \N somehow?
What I'm really trying to do is have IFNULL output \N for null values (and from what I've seen, using OUTFILE doesn't work across remote connections).

So the redirected version escapes the string literals it dumps in the file in a way that is appropriate for a contents of an .sql file, and the interactive version does not escape the string literals it displays on the screen which is appropriate for displaying on a screen... sounds correct to me?

@GSerg, I've found that it's not a difference between interactive or not and have updated the question with what I've found. The question still stands, though, as to how to output a single backslash or \N. If the escaping is correct, both of these should be possible when redirecting from a file (ie \N and \\N should output N and \N, respectively, or backslash isn't an escape character and those should output \N and \\N, respectively).

It looks like when redirecting from a SQL file, the only time backslash isn't interpreted as an escape character is when it precedes another backslash.

The following outputs what I would like:
$ mysql -e "$(cat example.sql)"
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| N | \N | SUBSTRING('\\N', 1, 2) | SUBSTRING('\\N', 2, 2) | CONCAT('\\', 'N') |
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| N | \N | \N                     | N                      | \N                |
+---+----+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+

However, when redirecting the output to a file, the contents again have the double-backslash:
$ mysql -e "$(cat example.sql)" >example.out && cat example.out
N   \N  SUBSTRING('\\N', 1, 2)  SUBSTRING('\\N', 2, 2)  CONCAT('\\', 'N')
N   \\N \\N N   \\N

At this point, this question is related to How to pipe to "null object" in bash?
